# how to fix the precision for calculating napier's constant

Tags: haskell

I tried to calculate the napier's constant *e* using the infinite array.

```
a = 1.0:0.1:[y/10 | (x,y) <- zip a (tail a)]
b = map (\n -> (1+n)**(1/n)) a
```

The result of first dozen of the number was ok but not for smaller numbers;

```
Prelude> b!!2
2.7048138294215285
Prelude> b!!3
2.7169239322355936
Prelude> b!!4
2.7181459268249255
Prelude> b!!5
2.718268237192297
Prelude> b!!6
2.718280469095753
Prelude> b!!500
1.0
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Your `a` works with `1.0`, `0.1`, `0.01`, etc. eventually the exponent can no longer represent anything, so then it is `0`.

Comment: By the way, in your code `(x,y) <- zip a (tail a)` is a complex way of writing `y <- tail a`, since `x` is not used (and `a` is nonempty).

Comment: Because of floating point rounding errors, `1+n` is equal to `1.0` when `n` is around `1e-16`. Hence the wrong result at the end.

Comment: You can have an infinite list of approximations, but that doesn't mean each approximation has infinite precision.

Comment: Stylistically, I would write `a = iterate (/10) 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is equivalent to the much more understandable

```
b = [ (1+1/n)^n | i<-[0..], let n=10^i ]
```

Note that each term is computed individually, so there's not much point in computing them as an infinite list – you might as well just compute the one that has sufficient accuracy right away and skip all the others.

The problem you're observing is that this algorithm is numerically unstable; it should not be used in practice. The problem, as chi remarked, is that `1+n` in floating-point arithmetic eventually evaluates to exactly one, with small enough `n`. And raising 1 to any power gives always 1.

You might think this could be circumvented by switching to exact arithmetic instead of floating-point. Indeed you can theoretically evaluate the above with the type `Rational`, and that would properly converge, however you'll find that it's utterly infeasible because the fractions get bigger and bigger as they're raised to a power, and the computation grinds to a halt long before you gain any advantage over the float version.

Also, this only works because I changed it from `n=10^^(-i)` and then `**(1/n)` to the integral `n=10^i`, which allows using the `^` operator. `**` supports fractional arguments, but that's not possible for rational numbers (fractional exponents correspond to roots, which are generally irrational).

The really ironic thing is that `**` is implemented in terms of *exponentials*:

```
x**y = exp(log x*y)
```

So your original version actually evaluates like

```
   exp(log(1 + n)/n)
```

– again, unstable (you get `log(1+n) == 0`), but at this point it would have been trivial to just take the limit analytically, which is

```
   exp((0 + n + (n²))/n)
 → exp(n/n)
 ≡ exp 1
```

– and, well, sure that is the Euler/Napier constant... but it's rather self-referential, isn't it?

If you want to compute that constant in an actually meaningful way, you should use a series expansion instead.